# why child class object refer parent class value

Tags: java

While trying to hands on the code I did not understand this portion

```
public class parent {
    int a =5;
    parent(){
        this.a =7;
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("In parent");
        System.out.println(this.a);
    }

}

public class child extends parent{
    int a =8;
    child(){
    }
    void print() {
        System.out.println("In child" + this.getClass().getName());      
        System.out.println(this.a);
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        parent childobj = new child();
        childobj.print();                      
        System.out.println(childobj.a);
    }
}
```

While `childobj.print()` print 8 why `childobj.a` will print 7 as this refers the same object?

Comment: Because `child.a` and `parent.a` are two different fields with the same name, and fields don't override.

Comment: Unrelated: please follow java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase.

Comment: my question is when object is created it will have a field value so how does it change

Comment: @abhishek it does not change. You read two different fields (with the same name), so get different results.